# n_tied_num.mdef and alltriphones.mdef for reading was not found

Tags: sphinx, cmusphinx

While I was training my native language (Amharic) using SphinxTrain-5prealpha.... Fatal error happened when creating the PRUNE TREE and Training the Context dependent models.

Training wav file is about 19 hours WAVFILE_SRATE 16000.

check [this link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10RXCFWWxfzkvSxLrCA3u4Pey6479H0iM_hxnRN2uCMs/edit?usp=sharing) to see **sphinx_train.cfg** file

[image]

The logs file are:
[image]
[image]

It is supposed to create it by it self. Is there any configuration that it is needed or configuration which I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

After the error happened, I looked into the files and folders created during the training process. There is a folder named **model_architecture** among others.
In the **model_architecture folder**, there are two mdef files including others. *YOUR_DB_NAME.ci.mdef* and *YOUR_DB_NAME.untied.mdef*. (my database name was amharic as you can see from the error log. so it was *amharic.untied.mdef*).

I **copied** both mdef file into the model_architecture folder and **RENAMED** *YOUR_DB_NAME.ci.mdef* to **YOUR_DB_NAME.3000.mdef** (3000 is n_tied.num, so it could be different for you) and *YOUR_DB_NAME.untied.mdef* to **YOUR_DB_NAME.alltriphones.mdef**.

If it is a directory that is missing, do the same.